# Update avdl (avro schema) field from required to optional (NULL) value

Tags: schema, avro, idl

My avdl is defined like this,

```
@namespace("my.event")
protocol Customer {

 record Address { 
  string street;
 }
}
```

But after the event is published and schema is registered, I want to make the `street` type to allow `null` value as well. I want the change to be forward/backward compatible. How can I do that?
Will defining a new namespace before record can do that? (https://github.com/ga4gh/ga4gh-schemas/issues/344#unions or https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-12.2.4.4/GettingStartedGuide/schemaevolution.html)
What about,

```
union{null, string} street  = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to make a field a no-longer required, you can wrap it in a null, with its existing type. I work with people that I see doing this quite often and the Confluent Schema Registry is set to BACKWARDS configuration for those topics.

Note: You can (and should) always [check the compatiblity](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/schema_registry_tutorial.html#passing-compatibility-checks) of your new schema before you publish events